# I can't get google cloud endpoints to work correctly, am I calling the correct public link?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

The api is tagged:

```
@Api(version = "v1", 
description = "API for interfacing with accounts", 
defaultVersion = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
```

and one of the methods I want to call is:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "account.register",
           path = "account",
           httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public void register(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{ ...
```

but I can't seem to figure out the url to access it :(

I tried POST-ing to myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/myapi/v1/account but it 404's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things...

1. I think one doesn't usually use Endpoints this way: by posting manually to a URL.  Instead, you are expected to generate a client library (which encapsulates the URL) and then use the client library.
2. If you just want to check out your endpoints, I've heard that the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) is very useful. For your specific application you'd use:

   https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer

   and be redirected to a version of the APIs Explorer for your application.
3. The actual calls to your App Engine backend are to paths such as this: `/_ah/spi/MyEndpoint.myMethod`. (**Note:** the `spi` versus `api` in the path.) The actual path you tried to construct is Google's API serving infrastructure acting as a frontend to your application.

Comment: To further point (2), the Explorer will show you the path it's using when you make a request. If you want to learn more about the URL structure for your API, this is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) in an endpoint.
The easiest thing to do is to make your java class (which you want to persist) and then in eclipse point at the java class and right click and select "google -> generate google cloud endpoint class" Then you get a good idea how it looks in different scenarios.
If you want to send parameters you have to add for instance myMethod( @Named( "myName" ) String name ).
But check out the endpoint genration first, it makes it all much simpler
And look here for more info: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations